# javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [2020-01-28T12:53:00.000+0000] of type [class java.lang.String] to [class java.util.Date]

Tags: java, date, jsp, el, date-format

In my JSP page, I have the field `createdOn` of type Date inside the object `circular`, which I am trying to display on the page as follows:

```
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="short" value="${circular.createdOn}" />
```

However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert [2020-01-28T12:53:00.000+0000] of type [class java.lang.String] to [class java.util.Date]
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:553)
    at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:304)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.user.circulars.circulars_002dlist_jsp._jspx_meth_fmt_005fformatDate_005f0(circulars_002dlist_jsp.java:700)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.user.circulars.circulars_002dlist_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(circulars_002dlist_jsp.java:510)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.user.circulars.circulars_002dlist_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f0(circulars_002dlist_jsp.java:430)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.user.circulars.circulars_002dlist_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(circulars_002dlist_jsp.java:322)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pages.user.circulars.circulars_002dlist_jsp._jspService(circulars_002dlist_jsp.java:163)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:335)
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.web.security.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:610)
    at ae.gov.adm.common.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Your variable `circular.createdOn` is a `String`, not a `Date`. So why not use simply use it to display?

Comment: What was your expected output or result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag JSTL  do not support java.time.LocalDate.
You can do some of this

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${circular.createdOn}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                       var="parsedDate" type="date"/>

<fmt:formatDate value="${parsedDate}" var="goodDate"
                       type="both" dateStyle="medium" timeStyle="short"/>

<h1>${goodDate}</h1>
```